# I am getting this error - FirebaseError: Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists with different options or config (app/duplicate-app)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore"; 


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PUBLIC_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID
}



const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
export const auth = getAuth()


export const db = getFirestore(app)
console.log('db', db)
```

I have tried the length thing but it doesn't seem to work with firebase v9. i need to export the db too.

without connecting to the db, the app works just fine.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible code? The snippet you posted seems correct to me. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

After lot of trial and error figured out :)

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import { logEvent } from "firebase/analytics";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.APP_ID,
    measurementId: process.env.MEASUREMENT_ID
};

let app;

if (!firebase.getApps().length) {
    app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
} else {
    // if already initialized, use that one
    app = firebase.getApp(); 
}

export function analyticsLogEvents(event:string, params:any) {
    let analytics;
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
        analytics = getAnalytics(app);
        logEvent(analytics, event, params);
    }
}
```